# Configuring Pycharm to use Pytest

Tags: pycharm, pytest, python-unittest

I have updated my integrated tools to use pytest as the default. When I select a click play on a test it uses pytest, but then when I try a different test within the same file it attempts to run it with unnittest. Was there a step I was missing? In the attached photos u can see its the highlighted portion calling unitttest. [usingpytest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiPCL.png)

[unitest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDyNQ.png)

I have set my Pycharm - Tools - Pythonintegrated tools to use pytest.

Comment: In your attached screenshot it clearly says *"Launching pytest"* and the highlighted part says *_jb_pytest_runner.py* (PyCharm's wrapper around pytest). So unless you mistakenly added a wrong screenshot, I don't see a problem.

Comment: Sorry about that I didn't realize it came out this way. the links should be showing correctly now

Comment: OK, no problem. *Settings... -> Tools -> Python Integrated Tools -> Testing -> Default test runner* should really be the only setting that controls what is the suggested test runner. Have you by any chance run the tests using unit tests, changed this setting to pytest and then run it again? In that case, I think it would be possible that the old run configuration is being reused. If you go to "Edit configuration..." (dropdown in the main bar) where the test runs are listed, you can delete existing/outdated configs.

Comment: That fixed it, On Mac I went to Run -> Edit Configurations -> and removed all the pytest templates. Now it is working thanks so much!